# Php MongoDB aggregation with match and sort order

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregates

I use this query in Mongo Shell to get the elements of the array 'events' in order by the value of 'start' field

```
db.collection_name.aggregate(
{ $match: {
    _id : ObjectId("59941bec47582c1e92b93c9b")
}},
{ $unwind: '$events' },   
{ $sort: {
    'events.start': 1
}})
```

But I don't understand how to do the same thing in php.
I have tried to write this without results:

```
$client = new MongoClient("mongodb://admin:$psw@localhost");
$collection = $client->db_name->collection_name;

$cursor = $collection->aggregate([
        ['$match' => ['_id' =>new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID("59941bec47582c1e92b93c9b")]],
        ['$unwind' => '$events'],
        ['$sort' => ['events.start' => 1]]
]);

foreach($cursor as $document) {
    var_dump($document);
}
```

I have tried also in this other way:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://admin:$psw@localhost:27017");

$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command([
    'aggregate' => 'collection_name',
    'pipeline' => [
        ['$match' => ['_id' =>new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID("59941bec47582c1e92b93c9b")]],
        ['$unwind' => '$events'],
        ['$sort' => ['events.start' => 1]]
    ],
]);
$cursor = $manager->executeCommand('db_name', $command);

foreach($cursor as $key=>$document) {
    var_dump($document);
}
```

Comment: Your query looks okay. Please consider adding sample documents that you are expecting query to return. Verify if you are connected to correct mongo server & db with right permissions by running simple find query.

Comment: yes, thank you. With the second code there was an authentication problem. I have added the db name in the connection url now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution. I have changed this line:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://admin:$psw@localhost:27017");
```

into this:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://admin:$psw@localhost:27017/db_name");
```

That was an authentication problem.